# Create div element and dynamically add child elements on it

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I create an element in javascript and dynamically add elements on it?

If I have this created element on HTML and dynamically append elements on it, it works just fine.

```
<!-- THIS WILL WORK -->
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

But this will not work:

```
// THIS WILL NOT WORK
var container = document.createElement('div');
container.id = "wrapper";
```

Additional code:

```
var html = '<div><ul>';

for(var i=1; i<=40; i++){
    html+= "<li>Testing: "+i+"</li>";
}

html+= '</ul></div>';

$('#wrapper').append(html);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jQx22/1/)

Comment: @wared - I just wanted to know if I can append elements on an element created using `document.createElement()`. Not on element I created using html.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's your code:

```
$(function() {
var container = document.createElement('div');
container.id = "wrapper";

$('body').append(container);

var html = '<div><ul>';

for(var i=1; i<=40; i++){
    html+= "<li>Testing: "+i+"</li>";
}

html+= '</ul></div>';

$('#wrapper').append(html);
});
```

Answer (score 8):

You have to call `appendChild(element)` to add elements.
For example:

```
var h1 = document.createElement("h1");
h1.textContent = "Title";
document.body.appendChild(h1);
```

In your case this is:

```
var parent = document.body; // or another one like document.getElementById("othercontainer")
parent.appendChild(container);
```

Comment: Is it not possible to append on an element created using `document.createElement('div'`)?

Comment: @JunM It's not appended, it's created :) You have to insert it into the DOM tree by yourself. Indeed, `document.createElement()` can't decide itself where it is supposed to append the DIV.

Comment: @JunM Complement of what wared have just said: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp

Comment: @dooxe Thanks for the explanation, +1.I will just mark Jokey's response as best answer. He still have low points and got it right also.

Answer (score 4):

You need to insert your wrapper in your HTML page.

This would work :

HTML :

```
<div id="layout">

</div>
```

JS :

```
var container = document.createElement('div');
container.id = "wrapper";

var layout = document.getElementById('layout');
layout.appendChild(container);

var html = '<div><ul>';

for(var i=1; i<=40; i++){
    html+= "<li>Testing: "+i+"</li>";
}

html+= '</ul></div>';

container.innerHTML = html;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Zd2rw/

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery like this:

```
$(document).append('<div id="wrapper" />');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an unsafe way of doing it. You can just edit the innerHTML as a string.

```
hd = document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0)
hd.innerHTML += '<style>body {background-color:blue;}</style>'
```